# Is there a possibility to exclude certain service calls for http logging?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, interceptor, okhttp

In context of https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor is there a possibility to exclude some service calls?
In my app are 2-3 HTTP Calls, where I dont want, that the logging-interceptor logs it.

Is there a possibility to override the intercept method in the HttpLoggingInterceptor class? Is there a possibility to write an annotation proccesor, which exclude/ignore certain service calls from logging?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the solution provided by mgohin on [this issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3727#issuecomment-352459944) with a little modification on the `HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level`. Example (in kotlin):

```kotlin
val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()

OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
            val request: Request = chain.request()
            // Create condition to exclude resource(s) from logs
            val logBody: Boolean = request.url.encodedPath != "/resource"
            logger.setLevel(if (logBody) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE)
                return chain.proceed(request)
            }
        }
    )
    .addInterceptor(logger)
```

If you would like to use an annotation:

```kotlin
// Create the annotation
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class DisableLog

// Add interceptors to the OkHttpClient

val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()

OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
            val request: Request = chain.request()
            val invocation = request.tag(Invocation::class.java)
            val disableLog = invocation?.method()?.getAnnotation(DisableLog::class.java)
            val logBody: Boolean = disableLog == null
            logger.setLevel(if (logBody) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE)
                return chain.proceed(request)
            }
        }
    )
    .addInterceptor(logger)

// Use the annotation on a resource
@DisableLog
@GET("/resource")
suspend fun fetchResource() : Response<SomeResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors are meant to be hooked with your **each http calls** so that you can observe what’s going up and what’s coming down.

**But to exempt fewer API calls from intercept, you can create 2 different retrofit client, one with OkHttpClient and other without any client.**

So you can request your Api with regular Retrofit client which you don't want to intercept, for rest Apis, use OKHTTP client with logging intercept.

Answer (score -1):

You can use two instances of OkHttpClient, one with and one without the interceptor:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClientWithLogging = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .addInterceptor(logging)
  .build(); 

OkHttpClient okHttpClientWithoutLogging = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .build();
```